# Uncaught Syntax Error : Unterminated template literal

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Please let me what I'm doing wrong here. I'm guessing this something to with  but not quite sure.

```
    var updateNewSKU = function(make) {
        var listItems= "";
        for (var i = 0; i < make.length; i++){
            listItems += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
        }
        $("select#NewSKU").html(listItems);
    }
    updateNewSKU(@ViewBag.NewSKUDrop);
```

In the console, I see the detailed error as;

```
    updateNewSKU(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `ViewBag.NewSKUDrop` content is a `List<string>` collection, you need to encode it to JSON string using `Json.Encode()` method:

```
var newSKUDrop = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.NewSKUDrop));
```

Or use `JSON.parse()` method after `@Html.Raw()`:

```
var newSKUDrop = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.NewSKUDrop)');
```

Then you can use the JSON-encoded list to pass into JS method:

```
updateNewSKU(newSKUDrop);
```

Note that Razor will execute `ToString()` when `ViewBag` property contains `IEnumerable`, hence the type name `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>` passed instead.

**Addendum:** If you're using NewtonSoft JSON library, use `JsonConvert.Serialize` to convert the `ViewBag` contents as JSON string.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: Don't thank in comments, just accept the answer, by clicking the tick. That will help others who read this question in future